# change exoplayer speed for certain duration of video

Tags: android, exoplayer

to change exoplayer speed we use `player.setPlaybackParameters`

this changes speed , but how can we set speed only for certain duration

the code that I have used is

```
playerTimer.setCallback(new PlayerTimer.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long timeMillis) {
                if (player != null) {
                    long position = player.getCurrentPosition();
                    long duration = player.getDuration();
                    speeder(position);

                }
            }
        });
```

and

```
public void speeder(long pos) {


        if (player.getCurrentWindowIndex() == 1) {
            if (pos >= 100000) &&
            pos <= 200000){
                PlaybackParameters playbackParameters = new PlaybackParameters(
                        2.0f, 1.0f);
                player.setPlaybackParameters(playbackParameters);
            }
                    else if (pos <= 100000) &&
            pos >= 200000)
            {
                PlaybackParameters playbackParameters1 = new PlaybackParameters(
                        1.0f, 1.0f);
                player.setPlaybackParameters(playbackParameters1);
            }
        }
    }
```

but the speed doesnot change when its between 100000 and 200000

Answer (score 0):

Notice:

```
else if (pos <= 100000) && pos >= 200000) {
   //the value of pos cannot be smaller than 100000 and bigger than 200000 Simultaneously
}
```

so the condition is always `false`